# Why does not onResume or onPause ever get called on my UI less fragment?

Tags: android

I have a UI less fragment. I have set the setRetainInstance. I was wondering why onResume or onPause never get called.

Comment: so would you share your piece of code, where you initialize your fragment, and link it to some activity?

Comment: It turns out that your statement _onResume or onPause never get called._ is wrong. The bug must be elsewhere. Without adding the **relevant code** nobody will be able to give a better answer than @Drew already did.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple test proving that **both** the `onPause()` and `onResume()` of a *headless* (without UI) retained fragment **get called** corresponding to the host `Activity`'s lifecycle, just *as expected*:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FragmentManager mgr = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment f = mgr.findFragmentByTag("mytag");
        if(f == null){
            f = new UILess();
            mgr.beginTransaction().add(f, "mytag").commit();
        }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.e(TAG, "paused");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(TAG, "resumes");
    }
}
```

Where `UILess` fragment is the following:

```
public class UILess extends Fragment {

    public static final String TAG = UILess.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.e(TAG, "paused");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(TAG, "resumes");
    }
}
```

This simplified (removed package et al) **logcat** output shows that both the methods run (triggered by a configuration change on device rotate), **no matter if the fragment is headless or not**:

```
04-16 13:47:39.840  E/MainActivity﹕ resumes
04-16 13:47:39.855  E/UILess﹕ resumes
04-16 13:47:48.623  E/UILess﹕ paused
04-16 13:47:48.623  E/MainActivity﹕ paused
04-16 13:47:48.751  E/MainActivity﹕ resumes
04-16 13:47:48.754  E/UILess﹕ resumes
```

Comment: I used the support library. Do you have the same behavior with the support library?

Comment: I experience **exactly** the same behaviour with the support libraries - *support.v4.\**, *support.v7.\**, and their corresponding ActionBarActivity, FragmentActivity, etc. **Everything works as I described above.** I have to see a portion of your code in order to understand how you've come to experience a different behaviour.

Comment: I have also tried your test now. Incl. use of different support libs and can verify that you are right. I am getting the same output. Looks like the statement "onPause/onResume not called" of the question is simply wrong. I was first believing the question, but I have changed my mind now, because machines don't lie ;-) Thumbs up for providing the evidence.

Comment: Yeah, they don't ;-) Thank you for double checking and for support!